# SQL Server: how to limit results based on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a customer table, and a customer address table but I want to limit it by just one address. so even though a customer has two postal addresses I want to show only one for each customer. Forgive me if this is a silly question, I am new to programming

```
custid forename surname
---------------------------
1       Sam      Supra
2       Kelly    Kenwood 

addid custid address          addresstype 
-------------------------------------------
1       1    Main street      POSTAL
2       1    2nd Main street  POSTAL
3       1    0712456254       Mobile
4       1    0526545686       LANDLINE
5       2    Second Street    POSTAL
6       2    04756325654      Mobile
7       2    058654236545     LANDLINE
```

Query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dbo.customers a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.addresses b ON a.custid = b.custid 
WHERE b.addresstype = 'POSTAL'
```

Comment: Which address would you like to pick? Just a random of the two? Additionally, which `DBMS` (Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL, etc) are you using; `SQL` is a language (I think it is SQL Server, but please confirm).

Comment: Yes, SQL server

Comment: You want to get only the infos (custid, forename and surname) of the customers who have a postal address, or the addresses too?

Comment: I would like to get the customer information from the customer table , along with one address from the address table (incase the customer has more than one address)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM dbo.customers c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.custid ORDER BY a.addid DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.addresses a
      WHERE a.addresstype = 'POSTAL'
     ) a
     ON a.custid = c.custid AND seqnum = 1;
```

Notes:

- Don't use arbitrary table aliases.  Use abbreviations for the table names.
- Presumably, you want to select the addresses, so I changed the `SELECT` clause.
- This returns *all* customers, even those with no address.  I am guessing that is your intention, although your query would return only customers with a postal address.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are interested in the last address entered:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.customers a
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.addresses b on b.id =
        (
        SELECT
            x.id
        FROM
            dbo.addresses x
        WHERE
            x.custid = a.custid
        AND
            x.addresstype = 'POSTAL'
        ORDER BY
            x.id DESC
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT      c.*, 
            a.*
FROM        dbo.customers c 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT    a.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY a.custid 
              ORDER BY a.addid DESC
            ) as seqnum
  FROM      dbo.addresses a
  WHERE     a.addresstype = 'POSTAL'
) a
ON          a.custid = c.custid AND seqnum = 1;
```